# Win RT / Metro Windows 8 Printing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Hi I was wondering if any of you know, if Windows RT will support Receipt Printers (For POS systems) or not?

I read this blog post 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/07/25/simplifying-printing-in-windows-8.aspx

However, its not clear if they support those type of printers, I was wondering if someone might have any idea about this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the print device has a Windows print driver, you should be able to print to it from a WinRT application.

Comment: that would be great... I will find a receipt printer on ebay that is already supported on Windows 7, than I will test it when Surface RT will be available..